# How to check if a node in a BST is unreachable

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-search-tree

```
class Node {

    int val;
    Node left;
    Node right;

    Node(int val){
        this.val = val;
        left = null;
        right = null;
    }

    Node(int val, Node left, Node right ){
        this.val = val;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

}



class BsTree {

    Node root;

    bstree(){
        root=null;
    }

    bstree(Node n){
        root=n;
    }

    public void insertpath( int val, String path){
        root=insertpath(val, path ,root);
    }

    private Node insertpath(int val, String path, Node n){
        if(n==null)
            n=new Node(val, null, null);
        else     
            if(path.charAt(0)=='X')
                n=new Node(val, null, null);
            else 
            if(path.charAt(0) == 'L'){
                if(path.length()!=0){
                path.substring(1);
                n.left=insertpath(val, path, n.left);
                }
            }
            else
                if(path.charAt(0)== 'R'){
                    if(path.length()!=0){
                        path.substring(1);
                        n.right=insertpath(val, path, n.right);
                    }
                }
        return n;
    }
}
```

I want to write a recursive function that tells me if a node is unreachable. The input is given by the user who writes the int values to add in the tree and writes the path from where the these nodes should be added in the binary Search tree.
For example:

1. `X` - number one will be the root
2. `L` - number two will be added to the left node
3. `RR` - number three will be added to the right, right

The path `RR` to add 3 is not valid because there isn't any node `R` before him. If this happens I want to print a message saying that this is not valid. How can i do that?

Comment: Some advice first: please indent your code and always use accolades (`{}`).

Comment: Furthermore what should be the result of `LX`? And what if the node already exists?

Comment: The result of LX or something ended in 'X' should return a message like "value not found" for example.

Comment: It should return "BSTree is not correct" Sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive method and the `Exception` handling mechanism to detect if the path doesn't exists.

```
public void insertpath(int val, String path) throws Exception {
    if(path == null || path.equals("")) {
        throw new Exception("Path is not effective or an empty string.");
    }
    Node node = new Node(val,null,null);
    if(path.equals("X")) {
        if(this.root != null) {
            throw new Exception("BSTree is not correct.");
        } else {
            this.root = n;
        }
    } else {
        root=path(root,path,0,node);
    }
}

private void insertpath (Node current, String path, int index, Node node) throws Exception {
    if(current == null) {
        throw new Exception("Illegal path.");
    }
    char ci = path.charAt(index);
    index++;
    if(index < path.length()) {
        //we're not at the end of the path yet
        switch(ci) {
            case 'L' :
                insertpath(current.left,path,index,node);
                break;
            case 'R' :
                insertpath(current.right,path,index,node);
                break;
            default :
                throw new Exception("Invalid path character '"+ci+"'.");
                break;
        }
    } else {
        switch(ci) {
            case 'L' :
                if(this.left != null) {
                    throw new Exception("BSTree is not correct.");
                } else {
                    current.left = node;
                }
                break;
            case 'R' :
                if(this.right != null) {
                    throw new Exception("BSTree is not correct.");
                } else {
                    current.right = node;
                }
                break;
            default :
                throw new Exception("Invalid path character '"+ci+"'.");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

It can throw several `Exception`s with several messages:

- `"BSTree is not correct."` if you want to insert a node on an already used path;
- `"Invalid path character 'a'."` (or something different than `a`) if your path contains a weird character that has no semantical meaning;
- `"Illegal path."` if the path cannot be used, for instance your `RR` example; and
- `"Path is not effective or an empty string."` if the path is not effective (`null`) or empty (`""`).

Evidently you can invent other `Exception`s so that a program can make an easier distinction between different problems.